# IIS: How change URL to include site name when browsing web files

Tags: iis

In my IIS, I have created "App1" as my site name and setup everything.

Now when I browse one of my web file from IIS, the URL for that page is something like "http://localhost/Folder1/Default.aspx".

But back to last time when I was using window 7, the URL that I can get is "http://localhost/App1/Folder1/Default.aspx", now I'm only getting "http://localhost/Folder1/Default.aspx" after I upgrade to window 8. I'm not sure if it's window 8 that causing the issue or anything, but I need advice on how to include the site name when I browse the file so that I can get "http://localhost/App1/Folder1/Default.aspx".

The reason why I need to include site name is because my entire project solution is calling files and web services that including the site name since long time ago. Without the site name, I can't run the program at all because I can retrieve data from any web service

Can anyone advice me on how to include site name in IIS? 
I tried Directory Browsing but seems not the solution in my case. I try search for how to include site name in my domain but usually end up directing me to Directory Browsing.

FYI, my application pool setting is as below:
.Net CLR Version: v2.0.50727
Managed Pipeline mode: Classic

Really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone face the same issue like me, I found my solution.

Yesterday I just thought of instead of searching Google for so many hours looking for how to include site name in my URL, I remove the App1 application in my IIS. Then, in the physical directory of my App1, I created one new folder call "Main" and I move my App1 folder into Main.

When I create a new application in IIS, i create new application as App1 but point the physical application path to "Main". This way, when I browse one of the web files in IIS, I can see something like "http://localhost/App1/Folder1/Default.aspx" which totally solve my problem, and my program can run properly now.

Although I still do not know how to include site name into the URL and why the site name is missing. But at least this solve my issue now